# Jquery Ajax triggered twice

Tags: jquery, ajax

for some reasons the function is being triggered twice. also if you can help me improve the codes (am a noobz) that would be highly appreciated.

the main calling function will be:
`get_range_entries`

once the callback returns the status it displays the modal box but somehow it goes to the next lines of code so its preventing me from closing the modal window.

```
function load_XMLDoc(dname, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "xml",
        url: dname + '&date=' + new Date().getTime(),
        success: function(result) {
            if(typeof callback === "function") {
                callback(result)
            }
        }
     })
}


function get_range_entries(view_name, startkey, universal_id, column, callback) {
    //unid = universal id
    //column = column number to compare
    //this is for uncategorized views only

    var url;
    var status = false;

    url = view_name + '?ReadViewEntries&ResortAscending=' + column + '&StartKey=' + startkey + '&UntilKey=' + startkey + 'Z&ExpandView';
    load_XMLDoc(url, function(result) {
        viewentries = result.getElementsByTagName("viewentries");
        entries = result.getElementsByTagName("viewentry");
        range_entries = viewentries[0].getAttribute('rangeentries');

        if (range_entries == 0) {
            status = false;
        }
        else {          
            entries = result.getElementsByTagName("viewentry");
            columns  = entries[0].getElementsByTagName("entrydata");

            if (entries[0].getAttribute('unid')) {
                unid = entries[0].getAttribute('unid');
            }

            if (unid == universal_id)
                status = false;
            else {
                colvalue = columns.item(column).childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
                status = (colvalue.toLowerCase() == startkey.toLowerCase());
            }
        }
        alert(1); ------------------> just using this to check if its being triggered twice
        callback(status);
    })
}



function display_message_string(message_title, message_string, hide_primary) {  
    $('#modal-confirm').find('.modal-title').html(message_title);
    $('#modal-confirm').find('.modal-body').html(message_string);

    if (hide_primary)
        $('#modal-confirm').find('.btn-primary').hide();
    else
        $('#modal-confirm').find('.btn-primary').show();

    $('#modal-confirm').modal('show');      
}



get_range_entries(view_name, startkey, unid, 1, function(status) {
        if (status) {
            display_message_string("DUPLICATE ENTRIES ENCOUNTERED", "The GENERATOR NAME you are trying to save already exists in the Database ... Please try again", true);
            return false; ----> added this just to prevent it from triggering twice but it doesn't seem to work
        }
})
```

..... next lines of code to save the form

Comment: Not sure it would help much, but would you mind updating your code with the relevant HTML? that way we can see exactly what you see and assist you better

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the function that's being called twice. Then you can look at the stack trace in the debugger to see where it's being called from each time.

Comment: It would be much better for everyone to debug if you post a live example on jsfiddle.

Comment: Without a fiddle, my guess is that its probably name clash. You get `callback` passed in to `get_range_entries` and `callback` executed inside `load_XMLDoc`. Try renaming one of them.

Comment: @PetrGazarov Why would that cause a name clash? Function parameters are local variables, so there's no conflict between the same name in different functions.